# Best aproach to percist user data in MVC across appluicaton?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, model-view-controller, static-methods

and I got information that in MVC we should avoid Sessions cos web is "Stateless", so I need to persist data( username, email and a list of string) across application, what would be the best aproach once that static class would be shared between users ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small explination of different data persistence that is available to you here:

[Data persistence choices for ASP.NET MVC web apps](http://petermcintyre.com/2013/01/27/asp-net-mvc-data-persistence-choices/)

> When a browser user/client accesses a resource in your web app for the first time, the ASP.NET runtime creates a “session”, which is simply a logical grouping of requests from the same browser window/tab during a limited time window.

As Carrie stated, using a session for what you want to do is the way to go.

Comment: related: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the information you got is flawed, but not completely inaccurate. Sessions are indeed a bastardization of everything HTTP as a protocol stands for, but they're also a necessary evil. However, it should be noted that in ASP there's a distinction between sessions, in a general sense, and `Session`, the object. For example, auth makes use of sessions, but it doesn't use `Session`. My personal advice is to avoid the actual `Session` object like the plague; that is really where all the cautionary "don't use sessions" advice is directed at. But, things like auth are a very good use for sessions in the general sense, and can be shared across applications as long as each utilizes the same machine key.

Comment: a minor nitpick: asp != asp.net

Comment: True. I was trying to generalize, but perhaps I generalized too much by removing the ".net"? I never really used classic ASP, but I'm assuming it had some concept of a session.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Chris Pratt, helped me a lot.